# Javascript innerHTML method returning wrong value

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for some support with this math's project I'm doing. Basically I've created four boxes, and populated one with the correct answer. When I click on the correct answer, the `if` statement doesn't run; it always shows as wrong.

I include a snippet, if someone can see something glaringly wrong then I'd appreciate a response.

I'm only trying it with box 1 to see if it works, and the correct answer does populate in 1 of the 4 boxes, however it always says it's the wrong answer, even when correct answer is in `box1`.

```
document.getElementById("box1").onclick = function() {
  if (playing == true) {
    if (this.innerHTML == correctAnswer) {
      score++;
      document.getElementById("scorevalue").innerHTML = score;
      hide("wrong");
      show("correct");
      setTimeout(function() {
        hide("correct");
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      hide("correct");
      show("wrong");
      setTimeout(function() {
        hide("wrong");
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, could you please update your question so that it shows all **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including your `hide()` and `show()` functions, along with your relevant HTML and CSS? It's a little hard to replicate this problem without it. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: can you provide a JSFiddle example so we can "debugg" it?

Comment: Start by checking what `innerHTML` actually equals by doing `console.log(this.innerHTML);` just before the `if` that checks against `correctAnswer`. As it is we can't help you because we can't know what `innerHTML` is.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing two values with `==`, try `===` in your if-statements.
Example: `if (playing === true) {`

Comment: This cannot be a correct answer. If the `if` was always returning true the OP would have said his project is always showing "correct".

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely related to your HTML, and the way you have setup your tags. For example, if `box1` is a div, then if your code looks like this:

```
<div id="box1">
    answer
</div>
```

Then in some explorers, specifically Chrome and FireFox, it considers linebreak as empty space.

So, if `var correctAnswer = "answer";`

and you compare `correctAnswer` with `box1.innerHTML` like so:

```
if (correctAnswer == box1.innerHTML)
```

Then you will always get `false` returned.

In order to fix the issue, change your HTML like so:

```
<div id="box1">answer</div>
```

Basically remove the linebreaks.

Everything else seems to be fine.